# How to get latest version history date and time in Google Sheets in a cell?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

When we go to File> Version history > See version history - at the right, there will be date and time (current version).  How do we get that date and time automatically in a cell in the same google sheet and keep on updating automatically when that date time changes.

Tried recording macro. Did not work

Answer (score 1):

You can use an onChange installable trigger. Run the createTrigger function on the script editor to create the trigger. The date and time of any change will be recorded in the cell A1 of the sheet named "Hoja 1", for example :)

```
function createTrigger(){
ScriptApp.newTrigger('onMyChange').forSpreadsheet(SpreadsheetApp.getActive()).onChange().create();
}

    
function onMyChange(){
  const cell=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Hoja 1').getRange('A1');
  const change=Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
  cell.setValue(change);
}
```

[Event-driven triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#event-driven_triggers)